# BLE different MTU for different implementations

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble, rxandroidble, mtu

I have tried different implementations of BLE connection on Android. One with RxAndroidBle and another one with simple Android API. I used RxAndroidBle example app for testing.
I connect to the same peripheral with the same service and characteristic. Though when I read or get notifications from it in the case of RxAndroidBle I receive 512 bytes and in the case of Android API - just 20.
I try to request MTU 512 but onMtuChanged is never called and I still receive 20. Do I miss something?

Comment: When you call [`requestMtu`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#requestMtu(int)) is the result `true` or `false`?

Comment: the result is `true`

Comment: Are you handling exceptions in `onMtuChanged`? If I recall correctly those are swallowed by default. Might be something hiding in there...

Comment: the method is never called, the only thing I see in logs is: `D/BluetoothGatt: configureMTU() - device: B8:**** mtu: 512
D/BtGatt.GattService: configureMTU() - address=B8:*** mtu=512
E/bt_btif: No pending command`

Comment: In fact when I'm also trying to call `requestConnectionPriority` i get this: `W/bt_l2cap: L2CA_UpdateBleConnParams - unknown BD_ADDR **********
E/bt_btif: Update connection parameters failed!` Any idea about that?

Comment: No idea, sorry :/

Comment: Are you trying to execute all requests at once perhaps?

Comment: No, I also I tried only to call `requestConnectionPriority` after connection is done: ` if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                boolean req = mBluetoothGatt.requestConnectionPriority(BluetoothGatt.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_BALANCED);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server and requestConnectionPriority: "+req);
            } else if `  still get the same results

Comment: Try calling the `bluetoothGatt` always from the same thread — on some implementations this may be an issue

Comment: Any news about your case?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure yet but I think it has something to do with the bonding and setting BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE option when connecting to the peripheral device.

Comment: This may be related. Different versions/implementations od Android BLE stack handle dual mode devices in different ways. Usually a better handling (in LE scenarios) is achieved when `TRANSPORT_LE` is required but [this may not always be the case](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/issues/439) probably due to wrong peripheral implementation. Feel free to add more information when available.

Comment: yes, it seems that since I set this parameter TRANSPORT_LE, max MTU is used, even if I don't set it explicitly. My device indeed is working in dual mode. Thank you!